# awk - field separator change in program, letters in the field

Tags: filesystems, awk

I want to change FS in awk, but not in BEGIN. I want to print word and the letter.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=""}{print $1; FS=" ";print $1; FS=""}'
```

Of course it does't work.
Is there any function, way to show words's letters?

Comment: Could you give a sample input and desired output? What exactly are you trying to do? Would multiple field separators do the job? What should an empty FS do?

Comment: I found solution couple minutes ago. I use "split()" function.

Answer (score 0):

awk is record oriented. It won't allow resetting the FS while processing the same line. Judging from the code you've written, you would like to take, e.g., this input:

```
First  
Second
```

and you would want to see as output:

```
F
First  
S
Second
```

One way to do that with awk:

```
awk '{print substr($1,1,1) ; print $1}' inputfile
F
First
S
Second
```